# how to set terraform module list variables

Tags: terraform

as i am a new bot to terraform, i am trying to create lambda permissions to multiple lambda functions using terraform.

**main.tf**

```
module "lambda1_s3_events" {
  source         = "./terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  statement_id   = "AllowS3Invoke"
  action         = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name  = aws_lambda_function.lambda1.function_name
  principal      = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn     = "arn:aws:s3:::${module.s3_bucket.name}"
}

module "lambda2_s3_events" {
  source         = "./terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  statement_id   = "AllowS3Invoke"
  action         = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name  = aws_lambda_function.lambda2.function_name
  principal      = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn     = "arn:aws:s3:::${module.s3_bucket.name}"
}

module "lambda3_s3_events" {
  source         = "./terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  statement_id   = "AllowS3Invoke"
  action         = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name  = aws_lambda_function.lambda3.function_name
  principal      = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn     = "arn:aws:s3:::${module.s3_bucket.name}"
}
```

and instead of creating multiple lambda permission modules as showed above. how can we create this three as one ?

i have tried add three blocks to configure

Comment: What is wrong with the current code? Are there any errors?

Comment: no errors. but i have 20+ lambda functions to add permissions. so i am trying to reduce the code. is there any way ?

Comment: So 20 Lambda functions will use the same S3 bucket?

Comment: yes. same bucket

Comment: What are the differences between `aws_lambda_function.lambda1`, `aws_lambda_function.lambda2`, and so on?

Comment: both are to invoke glue jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [`for_each`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each) meta argument on modules also, similar like resources.

```
module "lambda1_s3_events" {
  source   = "./terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  for_each = toset(local.lambda_functions)

  statement_id  = "AllowS3Invoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = each.value
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:s3:::${module.s3_bucket.name}"
}
locals {
  lambda_functions = [
    aws_lambda_function.lambda1.function_name,
    aws_lambda_function.lambda2.function_name,
    aws_lambda_function.lambda3.function_name,
    ## update this list with your lambda function names ##
  ]
}
```

you can do a couple of more possibilities with `for_each` here but I hope you get an idea.
This will enable you to use only one module call but loop over all all lambda functions.

> **CONSIDERATION:** Module support for for_each was added in `Terraform 0.13`; previous versions can only use it with resources.

Comment: i am getting ```The name "for_each" is reserved for use in a future version of Terraform.``` error with this

Comment: could you please check your terraform version if it is less than `0.13` , would it be possible for you to upgrade?